# Too many SOQL queries in developer console

Tags: apex

I am getting Too many SOQL queries: 101 in my code when I'm trying to execute in Developer Console window

```
String sAccountID = '0018000000wOgYR';
datetime DfromDate = datetime.now().addDays(-40);
  List<PreEmploy_Case__c> lstPre = [select account__c, Report_Case_Closed__c, Report_Closed_Date__c, Report_Case_Status__c from PreEmploy_Case__c LIMIT 5000];
  for(PreEmploy_Case__c op:lstPre){
    op.account__c=sAccountID;
    op.Report_Case_Closed__c=true;
    op.Report_Case_Status__c='Pending Automation';
    op.Report_Closed_Date__c=DfromDate;
  }
  update lstPre;
```

Comment: is there any other code in your DC. which you forgot to remove.

Comment: No actually there is only my code

Comment: try to reduce limit to 1000 and see.

Comment: I have tried this reduced by limit to 100 its not wrking

Comment: Did you check is their any trigger their.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found error line. This error was from trigger.

Comment: Yes @kumar I have explained the same things above, if Trigger calls was the problem,  Plz do accept my Answer - it will help others in future. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update record of object PreEmploy_Case__c from your Developer Console - and its giving you the "Too many SOQL queries: 101 " error. So, In this case

- you should look for the Triggers onUpdate of PreEmploy_Case__c this object.
- OR you should look if there is any WorkFlow rule, which is meeting the criteria of your newly updated record - and whether its actions are causing to call any other Trigger.

Let us know once you check around this cases.